# Load Balancing Tomcat Servers using IIS

Tags: iis, tomcat, load-balancing

Does anyone have any experience using IIS and basic network based round robin'ing to connect load balance tomcat servers (on separate physical boxes)? If so, any pointers you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tomcat's isapi_redirect module for this. There is a small [configuration manual](http://boplicity.nl/confluence/display/Tomcat/Running+Tomcat+behind+IIS) on my wiki.